# Aligning a linear system of differential equations

Tags: align, alignment, systeme

How do I align a system of linear differential equations in latex? I can use

```
\begin{cases}
x_1'(t) = x_1(t)-x_2(t)+2x_3(t)\\
x_2'(t) = -2x_1(t)+5x_2(t)+2x_3(t)\\
x_3'(t) = 8x_1(t)-5x_2(t)-2x_3(t)\\
\end{cases}
```

But I want the variables to line up better vertically with each `x_i` in its own column. I usually use the `systeme` package for this, but

```
\systeme{x_1'(t) = x_1(t)-x_2(t)+2x_3(t), x_2'(t) = -2x_1(t)+5x_2(t)+2x_3(t), x_3'(t) = 8x_1(t)-5x_2(t)-2x_3(t)}
```

gives me an error.

Comment: I don't think that `systeme` supports having the alignments *after* the equals sign. It's possible to have alignment if you are willing to have `x_1(t)-x_2(t)_2x_3(t)=x_1'(t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systeme` is not apt to the job. You might use `alignat`, but it's cumbersome. I propose `iEEEeqnarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCrCrCr}
x_1'(t) & = &   x_1(t) & - &  x_2(t) & + & 2x_3(t) \\
x_2'(t) & = & -2x_1(t) & + & 5x_2(t) & + & 2x_3(t) \\
x_3'(t) & = &  8x_1(t) & - & 5x_2(t) & - & 2x_3(t) \\
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`r` means a right aligned column, while `C` denotes a centered column with appropriate spaces around the operation or relation symbol.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to use `\syssubstitute`. Below, for example `A` will be replaced by `\mkern-22mu x_{1}'(t)` and `a` will be replaced by `x_{1}(t)`.

The `\mkern-22mu` and `\mkern-7mu` create a negative horizontal space.

Note the `%` at the end of the line to remove unwanted space.

Furthermore, `\sysdelim..` is used to remove the delimiters for the second `\systeme`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\syssubstitute{A{\mkern-22mu x_{1}'(t)}B{\mkern-22mu x_{2}'(t)}C{\mkern-22mu x_{3}'(t)}a{x_{1}(t)}b{x_{2}(t)}c{x_{3}(t)}}%
$\systeme{A=,B=,C=}\mkern-7mu \sysdelim..\systeme{a-b+2c,-2a+5b+2c,8a-5b-2c}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should put `\syssubstitute` *after* `$`, so the setting is local.

Comment: Thank you for this remark. If the settings provided by `\syssubstitute` are only desired in this one formula then it is indeed best to put `\syssubstitute` after `$`. But if more such formulas follow then, in that case, these settings would need to be repeated each time. Of course a macro can be created to simplify this. Another possibility is to place all those formulas in a group, if possible. I think that whether it is more efficient to keep these settings local or not depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can structure the alignment using `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{cases}
    \begin{alignedat}{4}
      x_1'(t) ={} &&   x_1(t) & {}-{} &  x_2(t) & {}+{} & 2x_3(t) \\
      x_2'(t) ={} && -2x_1(t) & {}+{} & 5x_2(t) & {}+{} & 2x_3(t) \\
      x_3'(t) ={} &&  8x_1(t) & {}-{} & 5x_2(t) & {}-{} & 2x_3(t)
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Additions of `{}` ensure proper spacing around binary relations/operators.